# call to Undefined method using laravel controller

Tags: input, laravel-4, controller

thats the error i keep running into when trying to post an event using my controller

$event= new Event();

```
        $event->name=Input::get('Name');
        $event->description=Input::get('description');
        $event->location=Input::get('location');
        $event->start=Input::get('start');
        $event->end_date=Input::get('end');
        $event->deadline=Input::get('deadline');

        $event->save();
```

Comment: What undefined method? Please show us the exact error message

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::save()

Comment: Looks like you're working with an Eloquent-Model named Event and it's interfering with Laravel's Event facade. Either namespace your model or prefix it with a backslash (`$event = new \Event;`).

Comment: i have tried that @Quasdunk even namespacing in my model

Comment: that is namespace project\models, but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

`Event` is a global alias for the `Event` facade from the Laravel framework. Instead of instantiating your model you are actually working with Laravel's class. To fix that you have a few options:

### 1. Namespacing

This is actually why namespacing was invented. To avoid naming collisions. You could put all your models in a namespace, for example `App` (this is how Laravel 5 is structured by the way)

Note that you then have to reference your model by namespace. Like:

```
$event = new \App\Event();
```

Or import it with a `use` statement:

```
use App\Event;
```

[Read more about namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

### 2. Rename your model

This is the obvious one. Just change the name of your model to something else.
For example `EventModel`, `FooEvent`, `Evnt`, etc...

Don't forget to add the implicit table name, since Laravel won't be able to derive it from the class name anymore:

```
protected $table = 'events';
```

### 3. Remove the alias

You could also just remove the global alias. Go to `app/config/app.php` and remove this line:

```
'Event'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
```

Comment: Thank you @lukasgeiter, i have renamed the model and it worked